# Can't delete iTunes Library in Finder nor in Terminal

Tags: terminal, itunes, finder

In Finder I get the unexpected error occured (code 50).

In Terminal I get:

```
 rm iTunes\ Library.itl
 rm: iTunes Library.itl: Invalid argument
```

See also:

```
charlesspencer$ ls -l iTunes\ Library.itl 
-rw-r--rw-@ 1 charlesspencer  staff  17222095 Sep 28 06:21 iTunes Library.itl .
```

How can I manage to delete these files?

Comment: Can you run `ls -dle@O . iTunes\ Library.itl` (that's the letter O, not the number) and add the result to the question?

Comment: Also I assume you've already tried rebooting and made sure iTunes or its helper process ain't running.

Comment: What's with the trailing space and period shown in the `ls` output `iTunes Library.itl .`

Comment: @nohillside, the iTunes Library.itl file can be deleted while iTunes and or its helper is running, they do not need to be terminated first.

Comment: Connecting the HD directly to the computer's usb port instead of using a hub fixed the problem, to my surprise.